# What determines if a bytea has 1 or 4 extra bytes?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, database-internals, bytea

When inserting a BYTEA string in PostgreSQL the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-binary.html) says that such a string will occupy 1 or 4 bytes plus byte string length.

The question that I can't seem to find the answer to is what determines whether 1 or 4 bytes are added and is this effect consistent or will it vary depending on some factor or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is in this header comment of [heaptuple.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/access/common/heaptuple.c):

```
* Before Postgres 8.3 varlenas always had a 4-byte length header, and
* therefore always needed 4-byte alignment (at least).  This wasted space
* for short varlenas, for example CHAR(1) took 5 bytes and could need up to
* 3 additional padding bytes for alignment.
*
* Now, a short varlena (up to 126 data bytes) is reduced to a 1-byte header
* and we don't align it.  To hide this from datatype-specific functions that
* don't want to deal with it, such a datum is considered "toasted" and will
* be expanded back to the normal 4-byte-header format by pg_detoast_datum.
```

Comment: So am I correct in the understanding that libpq will always return the byte string as the length + 4 bytes but internally it may either be stored either as 1 or 4 extra bytes?

Comment: The documentation page you linked to is talking about the on-disk "storage size" of the `bytea` data type. Toasting and tuple header overhead should be invisible at the libpq level. The data representation that you get back from e.g. `PQexec` is generally well-described by the libpq documentation (and pay attention to your setting of `bytea_output`, of course).