# ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "sometable_pkey"

Tags: postgresql, database-design, datatypes, storage

I have a giant table (500,000)+ rows with many columns that are `varchar` yes/no, and I want to reduce the size the db occupies, by changing the data types of `varchar` (yes/no domain), to `int`. Then relate that to another table with only two `varchar` entries, 'yes'/'no'.

I have the following SQL, (Postgres)

```
create table validvalues
(
    value   varchar(3)
        constraint unique_value
            unique
        constraint unique_value_new
            unique,
    numeric_value smallint
);


create table person
(
    first_name     varchar(50),
    last_name      varchar(50),
    has_permission varchar(3)
        constraint fk_has_permission
            references validvalues (value)
);
```

I want to write a script to change the datatype from varchar to int on the has_permission column, then relate that to the valid value table so that I can represent yes, no as 1,0 int and then when querying resolve 1,0 into the string yes no.

```
-- Update the has_permission column to change datathe  type to int and encode 'yes'/'no' to 1/0
UPDATE person AS p
SET has_permission = CASE
                        WHEN has_permission::smallint = 1 THEN 1
                        WHEN has_permission::smallint = 0 THEN 0
                        ELSE NULL -- Handle other cases if any
                    END;

-- Add 'yes' and 'no' values to the validvalues table
INSERT INTO validvalues (value, numeric_value) VALUES
('yes', 1),
('no', 0);

-- Add a foreign key constraint on the has_permission column
ALTER TABLE person
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_has_permission FOREIGN KEY (has_permission) REFERENCES validvalues (numeric_value);
```

I am trying this code to do this, been getting this error.

```
mydb.public> INSERT INTO validvalues (value, numeric_value) VALUES
             ('yes', 1),
             ('no', 0)
[2024-03-01 00:11:58] [23505] ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "validvalues_pkey"
[2024-03-01 00:11:58] Detail: Key (value)=(yes) already exists
```

I have been working on this for a while so I figured I would reach out for help.

Comment: i can't understand why you want to add the values if they already where inserted before in your code  > 
-- Add 'yes' and 'no' values to the validvalues table

Comment: I have a giant table (500,000)+ rows with many columns that are varchar yes/no, and I want to reduce the size the db occupies, by changing the data types of varchar (yes/no domain), to int. then relating that another table with only two varchar entries, Yes/no. added this as context to the question. Thanks!

Comment: that is a good idea but first you nee to fill the values tables the update by joining the values table and receiving the value from validvalues  and then convert the table, but still no idea wgy you tryto enter xes and no when theycre already in the table

Answer (score 3):

> I want to reduce the size the db occupies, by changing the data types of varchar (yes/no domain), to int.

That would actually **increase** the storage size on disk if anything. `integer` occupies 4 bytes and needs alignment padding. See:

- [varchar(n) size?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271722/varcharn-size/271750#271750)
- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860)

The natural data type for a yes/no field is (standard SQL!) [**`boolean`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html), which occupies a single byte, does not require alignment padding and actually reduces your disk footprint.

I suggest:

```
ALTER TABLE person
  DROP CONSTRAINT fk_has_permission
, ALTER COLUMN has_permission TYPE boolean USING has_permission::boolean
;
```

Yes, you can just cast to `boolean`. 'yes' and 'no' are valid string representations of true/false. But drop the FK constraint first.

Then drop the pointless table `validvalues` - unless it has other uses:

```
DROP TABLE validvalues;
```

Else, at least drop one of the two redundant `UNIQUE` constraints `unique_value` and `unique_value_new`. Having two of those does nothing useful.

You can add a view (if you must??) to display yes/no instead of true/false:

```
CREATE VIEW v_person AS
SELECT first_name, last_name
     , CASE has_permission WHEN true THEN 'yes' WHEN false THEN 'no' END AS has_permission
FROM   person p;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OO5x63Rr)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to take some time to consider it all and try your suggestions.  I knew that there had to be a smaller data type. :) thanks for getting me the right info!